# Arduino ADC values change after USB disconnect

Tags: arduino, adc, switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-divider

[image]I using an Arduino uno analog read function to read a voltage divider circuit for a voltage range from 0-70 VDC. On the voltage divider, I am using 2.7Kohm and 36kohm to reduce to voltage range from 0-70VDC to 0-5VDC for arduino analog input. 
The circuit works fine with the USB power to the arduino, and as soon as the I disconnect the USB, and the arduino switches to the backup dual switching power supply (120 VAC to 12VDC and 5VDC), the analog values change. 
The values are still steady and I dont see any garbage values, but there is a big offset between the original values and the values after disconnecting the USB power to arduino.
Can anyone comment with a solution to this? I checked multiple times and the ground is common through out the circuit.

Comment: A schematic would help... Otherwise the answer is, what is different when the power switches over.... which is not an answer either...

Comment: @Trevor
I have added the schematic for reference.
Please note that the schematic wont help much as the issue is somewhere related to switching the supple from USB to the external dual voltage switching power supply.

Comment: Yup it does not... how does the Arduino get its power when the 120V goes away?

Comment: Presumably, off of the USB bus @Trevor

Comment: @Trevor
It shuts off. But while it is connected to the computer USB port, it works smoothly even though the power supply is ON. As soon as the computer USB supply is disconnected, and the arduino starts getting power from the power supply, the analog values change. I checked the voltage divider voltage before and after i disconnect the USB, the values are exactly same. something changes in the ADC reference or something, not sure what happens.

Comment: I'd suggest there is a 5 V supply level difference between your AC supply and your backup DC supply. Since the A/D uses the 5 V as it's reference you would see a change.

Comment: Which source is used for Vref? Check and measure Aref out, and all Gnd voltages in both modes.  V REF can be selected as either AV CC , internal 1.1V
reference, or external AREF pin.
AV CC is connected to the ADC through a passive switch. The internal 1.1V reference is generated from the
internal bandgap reference (V BG ) through an internal amplifier. In either case, the external AREF pin is directly
connected to the ADC.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
I havent given any reference voltage. I thought that the arduino would automatically select 5 volts as its reference. and thats how it is supposed to be, isnt it?

Comment: @JackCreasey
How can there be a level difference between the AC supply and the USB supply from the computer?

Comment: If 5V was used as Vref and that changes 10%, does it correlate with your results?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
Yes. As soon as i switch from USB power to power supply, i get a 10% increase in my analog results.

Comment: that can only be corrected by changing the Vref to a stable constant value

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
I checked my default Reference voltage and it was 4 volts rather than 5 volts when operating on the external power supply.
If the arduino is USB powered, the reference is 5 volts.

Comment: I'm lost by your lack of clarity in question.  what are your actual ADC vs Vref vs Vdc errors and what do you not understand? Analyse error results in a spreadsheet.  Also be more explicit about Gnd vs Earth ground and floating ground.. Your schematic says it all. You have no idea about "star ground" and earth ground or EMC  and this leads to consequences of measurement errors.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 
I think you are making this a lot more complicated than it actually looks like. The schematic is a rough/quick drawing on something that i am testing here. It has nothing to do with my lack of understanding of drawing schematics.
My question was and remains very simple, why is that when i disconnect my USB power from arduino and put it on external switching power supply 5 volts, the internal analog reference voltage changes from 5 volts to 4 volts.

Comment: Can you not perform some tests to  trace back to the source of root cause?  Sensitivity to changes will tell you.  But first connect Earth gnd to 0V.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
I did try and test everything. I enabled an external 5 volt reference voltage instead of internal 5 volts, and still i had the same problem, the problem got worse in that case. the analog reading had an offset for 50%. its just that when the power switches from USB 4.9 volts to power supply 5 volts, the analog starts misbehaving. all digital IOs work just fine.I will do the earth gnd to 0V and discuss my results with u.

Comment: Put your response in your question with a table of tests and values.

Answer (score 3):

Read the Atmel [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf) for the '328

Section 28.2 cover the A/D
The inputs look like this:

[image]

By default on the Arduino Uno the ref voltage is taken from AVCC which is the 5 V VCC used by the MCU.

The Arduino schematic is [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf).

You can program the unit to not use AVCC/1.1ref and feed in a more stable reference ....or fix your supply voltage.

You could also switch to the 1.1 V reference and change your input divider.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I understand that i can change the reference to internal 1.1 V, but i am still trying to understand that if the default setting is 5 V that is provided by the arduino input, why would the analog values shift so much while shifting power supply from USB to power supply. Both USB and power supply are supplying steady 5 VDC.

Comment: We have no idea how much is "So much" and how much noise is on the system getting rectified nor ground shift with 3+ external grounds. (usb, batt, PSU)

Comment: @AmmarSurti. You have not supplied very much information ...how much does your A/D reading change? Are you measuring the voltage with a digital meter?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
I ran a few tests this morning:
I check the AREF voltage when USB port was providing power to the arduino, and it was 4.9Volts.
I changed the reference voltage to external in the program and provided exact 5 volts from the switching power supply. The analog values increased upto 2 times the original value. So if i was getting a value of 5, it increased to 15.

Comment: @JackCreasey
Yes i am checking the voltage with a digital multimeter.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
Another funny thing,
When the arduino is running on the external power supply and i connect my Computer usb to reprogram the arduino, the values get back to normal and it automatically fixes the issue.

Comment: That tells me you have a EMI problem with your signal input and poor CMRR.  Get twisted pair, shielded and add big ferrite sleeve.  The noise is getting rectified to DC from input nonlinearity.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75
There is no problem with the signal analog input. Under test conditions, the signal input is 3.9 volts, it stays there regardless of what power source the arduino operates on.

Comment: I'd suggest you try powering the unit from a USB powerbank. You then have comparative power systems ...the PC/USB and the powerbank. If the readings are ok for both of these then you definitely have a problem with your AC/DC power supply